# DNS relay: is that possible to do?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a dedicated server and I am using it as my DNS for my PC. (Linux server with BIND installed).

My idea would be to use opendns for filtering web content.

> > My PC<----> my DNS server<----->OpenDNS<-----> Web

Is this possible? Where do I start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You want to set up a forwarder in BIND to point to OpenDNS if the query is for an address your server doesn't hold a zone for. DNS forwarding is common. Read the **Forwarders** section [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html).